# Why can I not click on this element immediately after finding it depending on when in the code i try to click it?

Tags: python, selenium, web-applications

Just to preface, I've only barely started messing with python, and have no grasp on many python-specific concepts.

I'm refactoring some code and I'm trying to hide my janky error handling for getting selenium web elements, and I've come across a strange problem when passing elements around:

**selenium_handler.py:**

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
import selenium


def highlight(element):
    """Highlights (blinks) a Selenium Webdriver element"""
    driver = element._parent
    def apply_style(s):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                              element, s)

    original_style = element.get_attribute('style')
    apply_style("background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;")
    time.sleep(.3)
    apply_style(original_style)


def find_element(driver: WebDriver, xpath: str, url: str = "", test: bool = True, max_timeout: int = -1,
                 max_attempts: int = -1, time_between_attempts: int = 0) -> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement:
    if url:
        driver.get(url)
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = start_time + max_timeout
    attempt_count = 0
    element: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
    while time.time() < end_time if max_timeout >= 0 else True and \
                                                          attempt_count < max_attempts if max_attempts >= 0 else True:
        attempt_count += 1
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            if test:
                print("highlighting")
                highlight(element)
            # element.click()
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(time_between_attempts)
            pass
    # should only be past here if something went wrong so send error
    element.click()
    return element
    raise Exception("could not get element")
```

**main.py:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from real_project import selenium_handler
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# -------------------------------Cape Coral----------------------
cape_coral_url = "https://capegis.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=bbce9a471a534e7482d35716c4cb6f36"
time_for_elements_to_be_found = 5


def prepare_for_batch():
    driver.refresh()
    ok_button = selenium_handler.find_element(driver, url=cape_coral_url,
                                              xpath="html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button",
                                              # test=False,
                                              max_timeout=time_for_elements_to_be_found)
    print(type(ok_button))
    while True:
        try:
            ok_button.click()
            break
        except:
            pass


prepare_for_batch()
time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```

My error shows up on element.click(). As it is, I will get an error that the element is not interactable. But if I instead use the element.click() inside the try catch block then it will always work, no problem.
If I run the bottom element.click() in a while-try-break-except loop like the first then it will eventually click.

Why is this happening? It doesn't look like it's a race condition or that html is still loading up or anything like that or else the first element.click() would fail. I just want to be able to pass these elements around in my code. Thanks

**EDIT:**
forgot the code actually calling this function

Comment: maybe your code works too fast and browser still need some time to load it or scroll it to make it clickable.

Comment: @furas but it works if i call click() right after finding the element. it doesn't work if i try to click all the way at the end of the function

Comment: maybe you have different object in variable `element` - check at least `print(element)` - or you loaded other page - `element` will not work if you load another page. Or page loads other elements and all is changing in HTML tree.

Comment: @furas i made a temp element and had them compared and they were the same element. that isnt the problem either though, because they both click. the issue is i have to wait to click if i dont click immediately in that loop.